# Global Installation of Composer (manual)

Tags: php, binary

I followed composer [manual](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/README.md) (global installation of composer (manual)) to install composer on Ubuntu.

```
$ ll /usr/local/bin/
total 4760
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    4096 2012-03-29 08:29 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root    4096 2011-04-26 00:50 ../
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  410324 2012-03-29 08:28 composer.phar
```

Other scripts from `/usr/local/bin/` works, but composer gives:

`$php composer.phar update
Could not open input file: composer.phar`

It works only if I enter absolute path to `composer.phar`.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Don't add `php` in the beginning. Just call `composer.phar`.

Comment: It works, thanks. Explanation would be great, I'm curious. Thanks again.

Comment: It works because composer is already an executable (it has u+x rights by default). So, no need to execute php, because shell will do it anyway.

Comment: And there is a special code on the first line of composer.phar, `#!/usr/bin/env php` which tells ubuntu that the file is a php file and should be run with the php program.

Answer (score 200):

**TLDR;**

As described on the Composer [website](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally):

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

**Manual Method**

I found an easier way to globally install composer than the manual proscribed in [the github](https://github.com/composer/composer) `readme.md`. It's actually on the [getcomposer.org](http://getcomposer.org) website:

```
curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/
```

And if you're even more lazy, like me, you can create an alias:

```
alias composer='/usr/local/bin/composer.phar'
```

This way you can invoke composer with just `composer`

Comment: Nice. The alias is a sweet touch for obsessive compulsives too. Typing in file extensions? Pfeh! That's for chumps

Comment: Laziness, mother of creativity. Last update is the best !

Comment: when I run `$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` and then try to type `$ composer` I get the error: `bash: /usr/local/bin/composer: Permission denied` How can I change these permissions?

Comment: @ConnorLeech You can run `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer`

Comment: Since the last update is the best, I suggest removing everything before that update. What do you think, @chrisjlee?

Comment: @KimStacks I think it makes sense to keep it there context.

Comment: At least you move the best method to the top. That's good!

Comment: this is my adaptation of your wonderful answer. https://gist.github.com/simkimsia/0c218cadbb3055d53417 Only difference is I move it to /usr/share and made it accessible by all users

Comment: when I put `curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php` it says `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'getcomposer.org'` whats wrong with that??

Comment: @ThusithaSumanadasa LMGTFY: https://www.google.com/search?q=curl%3A+(6)+Couldn%27t+resolve+host&oq=curl%3A+(6)+Couldn%27t+resolve+host&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.296j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221642/following-url-curl-couldnt-resolve-host-get :)

Comment: Also, don't forget that aliases will be forgotten after you close the terminal session. You have to place that line to your .bashrc or .bash_profile file.

Answer (score 28):

Actually, [getcomposer.org](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally) now recommends a simpler method:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Now you can just use `composer` without bothering with an alias or a separate `sh` script.

Comment: This is correct.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative to get a nice `composer` command instead of `composer.phar`:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin
$ ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Comment: You can even use --filename=composer to save the symlink part :)

Answer (score 5):

for easier execution I created /usr/local/bin/composer with content:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/local/bin/composer.phar "$@"
```

dont forget about `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer.phar`

Answer (score 3):

Below are the steps to be followed to install composer globally:
1.
Before installing Composer, make sure our server has all dependencies installed.

1st, update the package manager cache by running:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

2.
Now, let's install the dependencies. We'll need

- curl => to download Composer
- php5-cli => installing and running it
- git => used by Composer for downloading project dependencies

Everything can be installed with the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl php5-cli git
```

3.
Composer installation with a single command:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

4.
This will download and install Composer as a system-wide command named composer, under /usr/local/bin. The output should look like this:

Output:

```
\#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /usr/local/bin/composer
```

Use it: php /usr/local/bin/composer

5.
To test your installation, run:

```
$ composer -V
```

Output:

```
Composer version 1.1.3 2016-06-26 15:42:08
```

6. Installation Successful

Answer (score 0):

I have made a [simple bash script](https://gist.github.com/EmpireWorld/1dd5f59566e186907f99dc16badc382a) that automatically installs composer for current user/all users, you can one of the following commands in your terminal to use bash script.

**Current User**

```bsh
wget -O - https://gist.github.com/EmpireWorld/1dd5f59566e186907f99dc16badc382a/raw/install-composer-local.sh | bash
```

**All Users**

```bsh
wget -O - https://gist.github.com/EmpireWorld/1dd5f59566e186907f99dc16badc382a/raw/install-composer-global.sh | bash
```

[**Check out the Gist**](https://gist.github.com/EmpireWorld/1dd5f59566e186907f99dc16badc382a)

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you. Note that `sudo` is used two times here.

```
sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. As it stands, it's not clear why the commands might solve the issue the OP has. Can you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/788118/edit) your question and elaborate on your answer?